# Interpolating a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography

I'm experimenting with some rudimentary ideas for data encryption (I've never formally taken a cryptology class). An idea that I had for an encryption was to use matrices. So I treat a data set as vector and apply a matrix (non-singular of course) to the vector.

So my question is two-fold:

First of all, how would someone go about finding the encryption matrix from the image and the pre-image? Like given $\vec{v}=A\vec{u}$, where only $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ are known, could one find $A$?

Secondly, how easily could such a code be broken programmatically? I presume it would be fairly difficult because the hacker would not only need to know the matrix, but would also need to know the matrix itself (or there could even be a set of matrices alternating between vectors).

Comment: I would recommend reading netlab.cs.ucla.edu/wiki/files/shannon1949.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle before moving forward. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If matrix A is $n\times n$, you need at least $n$ linealry independent pairs of $(\vec u, \vec v)$ to reconstruct $A$.
I hope this replies to both of your questions.

Comment: Yes partially, thank you. But what is the process you would use to reconstruct $A$ from those pairs?

Comment: It's simply matrix inversion:
if you $n$ pairs such that $v = Au$, you can write down all the $n$ equations collectively as $V = A U$, where $U$ is the collection of vectors $u$ column wise, and the same for $V$ and $v$. At this point, to solve your problem you simply take $A = V U^{-1}$